# How to display this unserialize data to blade in Laravel

Tags: laravel

```
public function getcustomerorder($id)
    {
        $orderss = Orders::find($id);

        $orders = $orderss->all();

        $orders->transform(function($order){
            $order->cart = unserialize($order->cart);
            return $order;
        });

        return $orders;
    }
```

The output of that from the controller is below:

```
[{"id":3,"cart":{"1":{"itemcode":"20062872","itemname":"AXE BS TWIST 50ML","quantity":4,"price":125},"2":{"itemcode":"20062881","itemname":"DOVE RO ORIGINAL 40ML","quantity":5,"price":50}},"firstname":"Joseph Vincent","lastname":"Limbaroc","phonenumber":"09197963942","email":"joseph.coquilla@outlook.com","street":"094 B Brgy. 40-D Bolton Ext. St.","street2":null,"city":"Davao City","province":"Davao Del Sur","zip":"8000","status":"new","created_at":"2020-04-20T05:15:09.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-04-20T05:15:09.000000Z"}]
```

How do I display the array of cart into blade using

```
@foreach($orders as $item)
     <tr>
          <td>{{  }}</td>
     </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: What output you are expecting??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Sarvil you could change the structure of your JSON a little. You can make "cart" to be an array not an object but I hope this syntax will help you:

```
@foreach($orders as $item)
     <tr>
          <td>{{$item->id}}</td>
     </tr>
     @foreach($item->cart as $item_cart)
          <tr>
              <td>{{$item_cart->itemcode}}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>{{$item_cart->itemname}}</td>
          </tr>
      @endforeach
     <tr>
          <td>{{$item->firstname}}</td>
     </tr>
@endforeach
```